# How does shell/kernel handle signals sent to processes within same process group?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, internals

In the section 9.6 of  *Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment* we can read:

> Whenever we press the terminal’s interrupt key (often DELETE or Control-C), the interrupt signal is sent to all processes in the foreground process group.

I did a simple test by writing super simple Python scripts, handling sigint signal and comparing results:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    p = os.getpid()
    with open(str(p), 'w+') as fh:
        fh.write("Received signal at pid: {0}".format(os.getpid()))
    raise SystemError()


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print("READ {0}".format(line.rstrip('\n')))

main()
```

I simply ran it like following:

```
$ ./reader.py | ./reader.py | ./reader.py
```

and ensured processes are in the same process group:

```
$ ps -ae pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm
$ PID  PPID  PGID  SESS COMMAND
  9702  5930  9702  5930 reader.py
  9703  5930  9702  5930 reader.py
  9704  5930  9702  5930 reader.py
```

My understanding is that after I send an INT signal to any of the processes, each should receive the signal and handle it with the handler. 
Sadly, this is not the case:

1. If I send the signal to the process group leader (pid 9702 in this case), all of the processes will terminate, but I can see only process group leader to call signal handler function (only one file created as handler call execution path)
2. If I send the signal to the process that is *not* a process group leader, the process will exit, handle the signal, processes from the same pipe (process group) created after will be also "silently" terminated.

   ```
    $ ps -ao pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm
    PID  PPID  PGID  SESS COMMAND
    9842  5930  9842  5930 reader.py
    9843  5930  9842  5930 reader.py
    9844  5930  9842  5930 reader.py

    $kill -INT 9843

    $ ps -ao pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm
    PID  PPID  PGID  SESS COMMAND
    1456  1446  1456  1446 weechat
    5893  5873  5893  5873 screen
    5928  5902  5928  5902 screen
    9842  5930  9842  5930 reader.py
   ```

I would like to understand why the behavior here is not aligning to what was described in the book (all processes belonging to the same process group terminate upon sending signal to any of them). Especially how is signal delivered to multiple processes but not all signal handlers are called. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: `press the terminal’s interrupt key` is **not the same** as sending signal via `kill` or other means. Press `Ctrl+C` in the same terminal where you run your executable.

Comment: I know it will then terinate all the processes, but my understanding is CTRL-C is just a way of sending a signal to a process group.

Comment: `but my understanding is CTRL-C is just a way of sending a signal to a process group.` - No, you are wrong. It is a feature of the terminal that it processes CTRL-C in a specific way. E.g., GUI applications don't process CTRL-C, but you can kill them via `kill`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured it out. My understanding was that CTRL-C would simply send SIGINT signal to the process grouop leader, however looks like this is more complicated and shell will take care of sending signals to each process in the process group.

In my tests the reason on why the signal handler was called only one was that other processes were exiting correctly. After calling **proc1 | proc2 | proc3** and killing, say proc1, it was handling the signal and proc2 and proc were exiting as the input was closed. Adding test sleeps() after the for loop shows that if I kill proc1 remaining processes will still be alive.